# Function with same name and parameter class name (but different parameter classes)

Tags: java, overloading, bukkit

I ran into a very strange problem that I don't know if I'm even allowed to do.

Basically I have two functions witch should have the same name but get different parameter objects which have the same name.

This is because I want to write a plugin for the game `Minecraft` and this should be compatible with BungeeCord **and** Bukkit servers.

```java
public static void sendMessage(org.bukkit.command.CommandSender p, String k, Object...i){
    //fancy stuff
}

public static void sendMessage(net.md_5.bungee.api.CommandSender p, String k, Object...i){
    //fancy stuff
}
```

If the plugin is loaded by a **Bukkit** server the plugin it doesn't know anything about `net.md_5.bungee.api.CommandSender` since this is a class of the **BungeeCord** server core and the same is for `org.bukkit.command.CommandSender` where it is used by **Bukkit** but not by **BungeeCore**.

I have no problem compiling the code with IntellIJ even dough I'm a bit sceptic because if decompiled it looks like this:

```java
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;

public static void sendMessage(CommandSender p, String k, Object...i){
    //fancy stuff
}

public static void sendMessage(net.md_5.bungee.api.CommandSender p, String k, Object...i){
    //fancy stuff
}
```

My first question is: Can I even do this, or will this give exceptions since not all Classes are loaded, even dough it will never get accessed?

Now if the first question can be answered by `Sure you can` then why is there a compilation problem by compiling eigther a Bukkit or a BungeeCord plugin using this `sendMessage(` function?

**Bukkit:** [image: Bukkit compilation]

**BungeeCord:** [image]

Because if this doesn't work I know for sure that you can at least work with Classes that aren't loaded if you put them into your codeblock since this code works just fine and isn't even throwing an exception when not loaded by a server that is using `org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_13_R2.entity.CraftPlayer` aldough it is in the imports:

```java
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_13_R2.entity.CraftPlayer;

public static int getPing(Player p) {
    String version = getVersion(instance.getServer());
    if (version.startsWith("v1_8")) {
        return ((org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.entity.CraftPlayer)p).getHandle().playerConnection.player.ping;
    } else if (version.startsWith("v1_9")) {
        return ((org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_9_R2.entity.CraftPlayer)p).getHandle().playerConnection.player.ping;
    } else if (version.startsWith("v1_10")) {
        return ((org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_10_R1.entity.CraftPlayer)p).getHandle().playerConnection.player.ping;
    } else if (version.startsWith("v1_11")) {
        return ((org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_11_R1.entity.CraftPlayer)p).getHandle().playerConnection.player.ping;
    } else if (version.startsWith("v1_12")) {
        return ((org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.entity.CraftPlayer)p).getHandle().playerConnection.player.ping;
    } else {
        return ((CraftPlayer)p).getHandle().playerConnection.player.ping;
    }
}
```

So is this really a thing I simply cannot do or is this a problem of the compiler of IntellIJ and if so how can I fix it?

Comment: Yes. If decompiled there isn't even a folder `v1_13_R2` in the Bukkt version `1.10.2` for example.

Comment: and you are sure that that other mod does not contain the given CarftPlazyer classes? maybe as a stub? maybe in a library? *normal* class loading need all referenced classes, not sure if Bukkit or Forge use a own class loader.

Comment: decompiled doesn't mean much, it is the user who specifies what and from where is decompiled

Answer (score 0):

Well my attempt to your idea would be to call methods in sub classes. It might be an issue that the non found class is a parameter. When the class is accessed (just my speculations) the parameters are tried to load to determine which method to use.

So something like the following would be the output.

In the class you access have:

```
public static void sendMessage(Object player, String k, Object...i){
    if(isBukkit())
        MyBukkitUtils.sendMessage(player, k, i);
    else
        MyBungeeUtils.sendMessage(player, k, i);
}
```

MyBukkitUtils:

```
public static void sendMessage(Object player, String k, Object...i){
    if(!(player instanceOf CommandSender))
        return;
    CommandSender p = (CommandSender) player;
    //fancy stuff
}
```

Same for MyBungeeUtils just with the BunggeeCommandSender.

I don't know your code, but if you have to have everything seperated you can just code two plugins (one for spigot, one for bungee) and use a include a library in both were the common code is placed.